# redis.py: How to flush all the queries in a pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, redis

I have a redis pipeline say:

```
r = redis.Redis(...).pipline()
```

Suppose I need to remove any residual query, if present in the pipeline without executing. Is there anything like `r.clear()`?

I have search docs and source code and I am unable to find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command list is simply a python list object. You can inspect it like such:

```
from redis import StrictRedis
r = StrictRedis()
pipe = r.pipeline()
pipe.set('KEY1', 1)
pipe.set('KEY2', 2)
pipe.set('KEY3', 3)
pipe.command_stack
[(('SET', 'KEY1', 1), {}), (('SET', 'KEY2', 2), {}), (('SET', 'KEY3', 3), {})]
```

This has not yet been sent to the server so you can just pop() or remove the commands you don't want. You can also just assign an empty list, `pipe.command_stack = []`.

If there is a lot you could simply just re-assign a new Pipeline object to pipe.

Hope this is what you meant.

Cheers
Joe

Comment: So, I will keep popping in a loop until command_stack is empty? That means there is no wrapper function for that.

Btw, I am assigning a new object every time, but the code has some threads, so I just want to be sure.

Comment: Well so long as your creating the Pipeline instance within the thread that is fine. You should never pass the Pipeline between threads.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
pipe.reset()
```

Other than the obvious advantage of ignoring implementation details (such as the `command_stack` mentioned before), this method will take care of interrupting the current ongoing transaction (if any) and returning the connection to the pool.